# Protractor: pass locally but timeoutt in jenkins, probably relating to promise things

Tags: angularjs, jenkins, protractor

Since I can't disclose any code in company. I can only describe the situation. Right now, I'm trying to fix protractor test for the angularjs webpage. Thing is some test cases work 100% fine locally. but always timeout in jenkins, it's probably some issue with promise. Cause no matter what limitation value I set for promise solving. It always timeout in jenkins.

In test. I use several method to wait for some element show up. Seems everyone is working fine locally. like waitforelement . iselementpresent . iselementdisplayed. But in jenkins console outlog, it always says timeout and waited at solving promise of element wait function.

Would it be the problem that I run multiple instances together?

Comment: My first idea would be that the Jenkins machine / the VM your are testing against is slower then your local machine. As long as we don't have an (example) script / log it's really hard to pinpoint where the problem really is.

Comment: Thanks! I did considered about that. What matters test speed most, CPU and RAM?

Comment: Yep, because of stuff is loaded in memory

Comment: Memory turns out to be pretty big 16g. Another thing, those timeout cases are random, every time, there would be several different cases timeout

Comment: Against what browser/machine are you runnering when you test from Jenkins? A VM, and in a cloud?

Comment: A real sever machine I think. windows 2012. browser is chrome, same as my local machine

Comment: It could be network latency too and the page maybe taking longer time to load. Have you tried increasing/configuring longer timeouts when running tests in Jenkins?

Comment: So default timeout for solving promise was 11s. I adjusted to 20s, still timeout all 20s. Maybe more time for that?

Comment: Cause these are all mocking data, shouldn't take that much  time to resolve(I think so, not sure)

Comment: Then I would like to see your script to be able to help you out

Comment: sorry for replying late. How can I contact you sir. seems there's no pm in stackoverflow